# how to get mapnik to render tiles from xml mapfile

Tags: tiles, mapnik

I have Mapnik set up on Ubuntu.  Tirex directs rendering requests from an OpenLayers client browser to Mapnik, which is set up to use the xml file below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Map background-color="#eeebe2" srs="+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs">

    <Style name="ocean">
        <Rule>
            <PolygonSymbolizer fill="blue" />
        </Rule>
    </Style>
    <Layer name="ocean" status="on" srs="+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs">
        <StyleName>ocean</StyleName>
        <Datasource>
            <Parameter name="type">shape</Parameter>
            <Parameter name="file">ocean</Parameter>
        </Datasource>
    </Layer>

</Map>
```

Tiles are generated, but they are all single-color #eeebe2 (from the Map's background-color attribute).  The polygons in the ocean shapefile do not appear.

**How can I make the tiles that are generated reflect the polygons in the shapefile?**

As an aside, I can run the following simple python script manually, and it outputs the image using the style that is defined in the xml file.  So I am missing some sort of step related to generating the tiles.  Is it a projection thing?  A server setting?

```
mapxmlfile = 'teststyle.xml'
outputfile = 'outimage.png'
m = mapnik.Map(800, 600)
mapnik.load_map(m, mapxmlfile)
m.zoom_all()
mapnik.render_to_file(m, outputfile)
```

Comment: As sometimes is the case, I seem to have stumbled upon the answer shortly after posting this.  Changing the srs of the <Map> tag to `+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs +over` has done the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment:

Changing the srs of the  tag to `+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs +over` has done the trick